# For Loops using colnames in R , increment i by 10

Tags: r

I had a bit specific problem in running `for` loops in `colnames` , increment `i` by 10 and creating new dataframe using `i`.

For example

```
x <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(3, 4),C =c(5,6),D=c(7,8),E=c(9,10),F=c(11,12),G=c(13,14),
                H=c(16,17),I=c(18,19),J=c(22,25),K=c(12,13),L=c(19,20))

# below create 12 dataframe starting from A to L which i do not want
for (i in colnames(x))
        assign(i, subset(x, select=i))
```

I want to increment `i` by 3, so I want my output as col A to C in one dataframe, col D to F in one dataframe, col G to I in one dataframe and col J to L in one dataframe, which means only 4 dataframes not 12.

Comment: tried to create a function          
incre_by3 <- function (x){
for (i in colnames(x))
  assign(i, subset(x, select= i))
  inc(i)<-3 # increment function from Hmisc package
}    # getting error Error in x + value : non-numeric argument to binary operator :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assigning to the global environment is generally not the way to go, especially from functions. You could do the following, generating a list containg the splitted dataframes.

Make a vector of indices where a 'new' dataframe should start, starting at 1 and incrementing by i.

```
i<- 3
start_indices <- seq(1,ncol(x),by=i)
> start_indices
[1]  1  4  7 10
```

Use `lapply` to generate a list of splitted dataframes.

```
res <- lapply(start_indices, function(j){
  return(x[,j:(j+i-1)])
})
>res

[[1]]
  A B C
1 1 3 5
2 2 4 6

[[2]]
  D  E  F
1 7  9 11
2 8 10 12

[[3]]
   G  H  I
1 13 16 18
2 14 17 19

[[4]]
   J  K  L
1 22 12 19
2 25 13 20
```

Comment: Wonderful ,awesome solution made my day .Thank you very much

Comment: I don't want to beat my own drum, but if you're satisfied could you accept the answer? Keeps others from spending time on the question.

Comment: Sorry I m new to Stackoverflow not sure how to accept the answer ?

Comment: @Mahendra I you think this is the best answer, then you should accept this answer and not the other

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your approach

```
> for (i in 1:(ncol(x)/3))
+         assign(names(x)[3*i-2], subset(x, select=(3*i-2):(3*i)))
> A
  A B C
1 1 3 5
2 2 4 6
> D
  D  E  F
1 7  9 11
2 8 10 12
> G
   G  H  I
1 13 16 18
2 14 17 19
> J
   J  K  L
1 22 12 19
2 25 13 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought to add last line on unlisting list ,previous answer by Heroka

#### create multiple data frame from list of

`for(i in 1:length(res)) {
  assign(paste0("gf", i), res[[i]])`
}